# Google reCaptcha get response

Tags: response, recaptcha

According to this example (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#example) by google

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var verifyCallback = function(response) {
    alert(response);
  };

    grecaptcha.render('example3', {
      'sitekey' : 'your_site_key',
      'callback' : verifyCallback,
      'theme' : 'dark'
    });
  };
</script>


 <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="example3"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
```

I should receive response message and get the alert it but when I try it doesn't display any response and even doesn't call method  verifyCallback

I should receive a response after widget rendering, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have nothing that causes the `grecaptcha.render(...` to run.

It needs to be in a handler so that something causes it to run.

`verifyCallback` should then run as you have correctly specified in the `callback` parameter

Answer (score -1):

Your callback name should match the callback name passed to the API:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var onloadCallback = function(response) {
    alert(response);
  };

    grecaptcha.render('example3', {
      'sitekey' : 'your_site_key',
      'callback' : verifyCallback,
      'theme' : 'dark'
    });
  };
</script>



<form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="example3"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
```

Comment: `onload=onloadCallback` in the `<script>` tag says what to run when the script has loaded.  It is not involved in the validation.  It's not needed here and should be removed.